# How to adapt height of a div to the height of an absolute div inside of it?

Tags: css, height, css-position

I'm struggling with these div's lately. For instance, look at this code below:

```
<div class="container">
{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
    <div class="content">
    {
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
        <div class="upload">
        {
            width: 400px;
            margin-left: 600px;
            position: absolute;
        }
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer>

    </div>
</div>
```

First a small draw of what is actually on the screen (coudn't draw it any nicer):

```
--------------------------------------
|               CONTAINER            |
|   _____________________________    |
|   [       CONTENT   = = = =  =]    |
|   [                 = UPLOAD =]    |
|   [                 =        =]    |
|   [                 =        =]    |
|   [                 =        =]    |
|   [                 =        =]    |
|   [                 =        =]    |
|   [                 =        =]    |
|   [                 =        =]    |
|   [                 =        =]    |
|   [                 = = = = = ]    |
|   [                           ]    |
|   [                           ]    |
|   [                           ]    |
|   [                           ]    |
|   [                           ]    |
|   [                           ]    |
|   [                           ]    |
|   [___________________________]    |
|   _____________________________    |
|   [          FOOTER           ]    |
|   [___________________________]    |
--------------------------------------
```

When the class `upload` gets bigger in height, it floats outside of the `container` and `content` div, because of the absolute positioning.

I need to find a way to adjust this `container`'s or `content`'s size to the `upload` div.

When I style the upload class like this:

```
position: relative;
float: right;
padding-right: 500px;
```

It works, but only at this resolution. If you zoom in, this padding messes up the `content` (on the left side) and the `upload` (on the right side). Keeping the margin-left how it now is, is good, because there are things left of the `upload` div which require this minimal space on whatever resolution.

So anyone...
Any ideas?

**EDIT**

For a second I though I had it.

The problem if you give `upload` the attribute `position: relative` in my case is that it pushes everything inside the content beneat the `upload` div....

So I replaced the `.upload` with `position: relative;` and added a new div around whatever is inside the `content` (except for the `upload` ofcourse)

```
.insidecontent
{
float: left;
position: absolute;
top: 170px;
}
```

But now the `content` height equals to the height of `upload` and when it's smaller than the `content`'s or `.insidecontent`'s it gets cut off.

I'm sorry I can't give a good code example in jsfiddle, it's not really showing what I see on my webpage.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You are mixing up HTML and CSS

Comment: Ofcourse the HTML and CSS codes are seperate. The code here is just for the idea.

Comment: @IvanM Past it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: i did, you don't want to see what it generated haha

Answer (score 2):

you can use relative positioning which will help you a lot. Update your code with following details

```
.upload{
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    top: -24%;
    left: 69%;    
}
```

[Sample Code](http://jsfiddle.net/yhsaA/)

Comment: Doesnt really work. My forms inside the content become under the upload div. Or do i have to place the form in a new div?

Comment: I think better not to work with percentages though, it messes up when zooming in or out the page.